# Incompatible JVM when trying to install Eclipse on Windows 10 PC

Tags: java, installation

I am trying to run the installer for Eclipse 64-bit and I get an error message:

```
Version 1.7.0_10 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.8 or greater is required.
```

When i run `java -version` on the command line, I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Please help, i just want to get up and running with Eclipse.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check if there is a JAVA_HOME variable set. That might point to the Java7 installation and put the eclipse installer on the wrong track

Comment: I am VERY new to programming and have no formal training. Where would i find such a thing?

Comment: Just search environment variables in start menu it will pop up an option which states 'edit system environment variables'. Click on that. 
Then on the bottom right corner you'll see environment variables button. Click on it. Check if there's a JAVA_HOME variable on the left side of the screen

Comment: I found that variable and it pointed to jdk 1.7.0. I will DL 1.8 and see if that works

Comment: My JDK was on previous version so i installed new JDK and I edited the JAVA_HOME environment variable to 1.8.0 and now the Eclipse installer has functioned. Thanks, to both of you.

Answer (score 41):

follow this steps

step1 : just go and find the **location of eclipse** in your system

step2 : open the "**eclipse configuration file**" and search "**-vmargs**" in
this file
just **go one line above of** "-vmargs" and hit enter for blank space
now type here "**-vm**" and hit enter

step3 : go and **copy the bin folder of jdk11**
and paste it below the "-vm"
then append this "**\javaw.exe**", see the demo below
then save it and now run the eclipse ide

example in my case

**-vm**

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9\bin\javaw.exe**

**-vmargs**

Comment: This should be the `eclipse.ini` file

Answer (score 13):

I had the problem with STS 4 on Windows 10 that needed JVM V11.

After JDK installation, you must add the bin path of the JDK in your `PATH` environment variable, in the first position, to ensure the system will use the right version.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like STS4 is not compatible with jdk1.8 ? It needs 11 or higher

Comment: Make sure it's `System variables` and not `User variables` in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the JAVA_HOME in the same cmd that you run the executable Eclipse installation File. Example:

> set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171" 
>   "C:\Users\XX\Downloads\eclipse-inst-win64.exe"

Answer (score 0):

recently I got the same issue with STS. i have issued below command in cmd with admin rights:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin"

its resolved my problem. hope it will work for you.

Comment: I think adding JAVA_HOME to the env variable will be better then using cmd

Comment: correct, but sometimes its won't reflect immediately, so the proposed way is good as per my knowledge. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI:
Installing multiple JDKs/JREs led to Eclipse detecting the wrong one (jdk 8 instead of the required 11).
Aside from setting JAVA_HOME I had to reorder the PATH variable, to have the 11 before the 8.

Answer (score 0):

One solution if none of the others work: You have two types of system variables, user and the system. You need to remove all the paths (relative and absolute) that point to any version of java from the system variable part. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue, with using java 17.

I changed the environment variable path to

> jdk17\bin\javaw.exe

eg:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.3.1\bin\javaw.exe

after this it worked fine for me